# memcpy confusion overflow / overwriting with gcc?

Tags: c, memcpy

Not sure what im doing wrong here. Im guessing its memory alignment issue but its confusing as to why that would be occurring. Tested locally with gcc 7.4.0 and onlinegdb.com. (can copy code here and paste / compile to confirm)

Works with converting data types to char/uint8_t but int or short/uint16_t does not work (data2 struct member gets modified).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int *data;
    int *data2;
};

struct test *Test=NULL;
int buffer[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

int main()
{
    Test = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    memset(Test, 0, sizeof(struct test));

    printf("Before memcpy %d\r\n", Test->data2);

    Test->data = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
    memcpy(&Test->data, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    printf("After memcpy %d\r\n", Test->data2);

    return 0;
}


data2 struct member is expected to be 0, however the value has changed after the memcpy for struct member data is executed.

Output:

Before memcpy 0
After memcpy 3
```

Comment: I suspect you meant `memcpy(Test->data, buffer, sizeof(buffer))` with (no `&`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "simple typographical error"; Remove `&` and the result should be fine.

Comment: ah yes that's correct. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `memcpy(&Test->data, buffer, sizeof(buffer));`

You are passing the address of variable `data`, which is a pointer, and copying to it more bytes than its boundaries, that is why variable `data2` is modified (as a pointer, `Test->data` have 4 or 8 bytes depending on the architecture you are running the code).

You probably want to pass `Test->data` to `memcpy` as its `dst` parameter, not `&Test->data`.

Comment: ah yes that is correct